# Sliding up or down an entire HTML table using jquery, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking for a solution but I couldn't find it. I even tried this from SO, [div will slidedown but it wont slideup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750773/div-will-slidedown-but-it-wont-slideup)

Basically I'm using the `slideUp()` from jquery on a table but it doesn't slide up, instead it just dissappear.

I've done the `float: none` on the table, add `position: relative` to the parent element. But it still doesn't show the sliding effect.

jquery:

```
$('#voucher-btn').click(function(e){
    $('#voucher-list').slideUp(400);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="main">

 <ul>
  <li><label>Scratch-off Panel</label><input type="text" id="scratch-panel" /></li> 
  <li><label>Serial Number</label><input class="field-small" type="text" id="serial-num" /></li>
  <!--<li><button class="but-sec" id="voucher-btn" type="submit" title="Apply">Apply</button></li>-->
  <li><input class="but-sec" type="submit" id="voucher-btn" value="Apply" /></li>
 </ul>

 <table id="voucher-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="200px">$Value One</th><th>$Value Two</th><th>$Value Three</th><th>$Value Four</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>MSFRGFCHGGKJVJ1234</td><td>12345678</td><td>£156678</td><td>Remove</td>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
 width: 700px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 position: relative;
}

#voucher-list{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 float: none;
 position: relative;
}

#voucher-list td, th{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}

li{
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

input[type="text"]{
 float: left;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

label{
 float: left;
 width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the Table in a Div and use the slideUp function on the Div.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tables are finicky and you should avoid using effects on a table directly. What does work is wrapping a div around your table and applying your effect to that instead.

You don't have the same control over tables as you do other elements.  Which is why blindUp can't change the height of the table during animation.

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BQTGF/

Comment: Is it the same technique for `td, tr`, and other table elements?

Comment: You cannot wrap a div around td, tr, th unfortunately because it would be invalid mark-up.

Comment: Never knew jquery slideup/down wouldn't work directly on HTML table. Wrapped `<div>` around it and it worked. Apprec.

Answer (score 4):

A table is not a block level element, so its height and width are not settable. In order to get this to work, wrap the table in a block level element, such as a div tag, and perform the slideUp on the div

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <table id="voucher-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="200px">$Value One</th><th>$Value Two</th><th>$Value Three</th><th>$Value Four</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>MSFRGFCHGGKJVJ1234</td><td>12345678</td><td>£156678</td><td>Remove</td>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

$('#voucher-btn').click(function(e){
    $('#wrapper').slideUp(400);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to remove the table, using `.wrapAll(...)` will prevent you having to embellish your markup with unnecessary tags.

The following example adds the div dynamically when it's needed to slide the table closed, and then removes the table (and the temporary div):

```
$('#tableId').wrapAll('<div />').closest('div').slideUp(1000, function () {
    $('#tableId').closest('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is  wrap the whole table in a division and then use toggle method as follows:

```
$('<table id>').wrapInner('<div></div>').toggle('slide', { direction: "direction" }, speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I learn something about javaScript this last days and i think this code may help you:

```
    $(document).ready(function()  {
    // Hide the table tags
     $("table").hide();

     $("h1").click(function() {
         $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
         });

});
```

What this code should do is that with  the tag "H1" clicking it should hide the tag "Table"
But i look a bit messed the slide thing but is there Hide and Show. Hope i Help